# Button not working(No color change)

Tags: android, button

I just create a new project with blank activity and then drag and drop a Button. When i run it on a 2.3.6 samsung i9000 the button has the same background both when pressed or unpressed.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="39dp" />
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARjSD.png

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? (What is your question?)
What have you tried ?

Comment: ...and if you run it on another device, it doesn't? Or..? What is your point? Is it a problem specific to the Samsung device, to version 2.3.6 of Android, or is it the same regardless of which device you're running on? It would be helpful with some context and an explanation of the expected behavour.

Comment: I was just doing some work at an app and noticed that when i add buttons they don't have that visual effects of a default button. So i tried to just make an empty app and simply drag and drop a button to check if this problem persists, and it did. On a tablet(Samsung N8010 with 4.4)  though, it work just as intended.

Answer (score 0):

in android a button with default background ,when pressed it and release dos not have any changes in color or other options,
you can set two background for it and when call setonclick , in a thread changes background of button

Comment: On a Samsung N8010 with android 4.4 tablet it works like a normal button(at least visually), meaning that, by default it has a different background and that it changes when pressed

Comment: but On a HTC desire 616 with android 4.2 it dos not work with normal button,meaning that, by default it has not a different background and that it changes when pressed

Answer (score -1):

use android:background="#EEEEEE" to change the background color. Use this attribute in your button tag.

For click activities, you would need to change the background property programatically.

Comment: Why would hard-coding a color without no connection to the device theme or anything like that be a good idea?

Comment: It is just an example. The user can use whatever suits the theme.